# OptionOutputOriginalCase not working in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to replace some text using HtmlAgilityPack in Html string and placing ASP.net user controls but I am getting lower case in output html. Any Idea how to get original case output.

Code :

```
        public static string ConvertPageTitlesToCMSTitle(string htmlstring, string themeSlug)
        {
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
                {
                    OptionOutputOriginalCase = true,
                    OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true
                };

            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);

            var stPageTitleTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//stpagetitle");

            foreach (var stPageTitleTag in stPageTitleTags)
            {
                var pageTitle = Strings.StripHTML(stPageTitleTag.InnerText);
                pageTitle = pageTitle.Trim();

                var pageId = CreateUpdateContentPageInDb(pageTitle, themeSlug, null, null);

                var widgetControl = string.Format("<widget:PageTitleDisplay runat=\"server\" PageId=\"{0}\" Editable=\"True\" />", pageId);

                htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Replace(stPageTitleTag.OuterHtml, widgetControl);
            }

            return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `widget:PageTitleDisplay` is an element in a specific namespace, and Html Agility Pack doesn't fully support namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could create a text node instead of HTML node. See:

```
foreach (var stPageTitleTag in stPageTitleTags)
{
    var pageTitle = Strings.StripHTML(stPageTitleTag.InnerText);
    pageTitle = pageTitle.Trim();

    var pageId = CreateUpdateContentPageInDb(pageTitle, themeSlug, null, null);

    var widgetControl = string.Format("<widget:PageTitleDisplay runat=\"server\" PageId=\"{0}\" Editable=\"True\" />", pageId);

    // creating a text node
    var widget = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(widgetControl);
    // replacing <sppagetitle> node with the new one
    stPageTitleTag.ReplaceChild(widget, stPageTitleTag);
}
```

This should get the output you want.

Comment: its not changing case of my new added string but also existing html tags all